# javascript plugin working only ctrl+F5

Tags: javascript, caml

im test new template and using camljs lib.

next step to read javascript not work a loop, becouse read htmlcollection aint return length.

i can view returns only refreshing with ctrl+F5 or ctrl+shift+R in chrome.

```
function click() {          
            console.log('teste de documento',document.querySelectorAll( '.morph-button' ));
            var len = document.getElementsByClassName( 'morph-button' );
            console.log('teste de documento', len.length);

            var nodes = document.querySelectorAll( '.morph-button' );
                var docElem = window.document.documentElement, didScroll, scrollPosition;


                function noScrollFn() {
                    window.scrollTo( scrollPosition ? scrollPosition.x : 0, scrollPosition ? scrollPosition.y : 0 );
                }

                function noScroll() {
                    window.removeEventListener( 'scroll', scrollHandler );
                    window.addEventListener( 'scroll', noScrollFn );

                }

                function scrollFn() {
                    window.addEventListener( 'scroll', scrollHandler );
                }

                function canScroll() {
                    window.removeEventListener( 'scroll', noScrollFn );
                    scrollFn();
                }

                function scrollHandler() {
                    if( !didScroll ) {
                        didScroll = true;
                        setTimeout( function() { scrollPage(); }, 60 );
                    }
                };

                function scrollPage() {
                    scrollPosition = { x : window.pageXOffset || docElem.scrollLeft, y : window.pageYOffset || docElem.scrollTop };
                    didScroll = false;
                };

                scrollFn();


                console.log('this', this.target);
                console.log('state2', document.readyState);

                    var list = document.getElementsByClassName('morph-button');
                    console.log('list', list.length);

                   // var i;

                    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                        console.log('list iteration', list);
                        console.log('list index', i);

                        new UIMorphingButton( list[i], {
                            closeEl: '.icon-close',
                            onBeforeOpen: function () {

                                noScroll();

                            },
                            onAfterOpen: function () {

                                canScroll();

                            },
                            onBeforeClose: function () {

                                noScroll();

                            },
                            onAfterClose: function () {

                                canScroll();

                            }
                        });

                    }

}
window.onload = click;
```

Comment: Does the site you are running this on have the Minimal Download Strategy feature enabled?

Comment: Hey @DylanCristy, it is disable.

Comment: @DylanCristy i resolve the problem, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[resolved]

hey, i resolved the problem with MutationOberver

```
                var divArray = document.getElementById('atividades');

                var observer = new MutationObserver(function(){
                   console.log('observer1', document.getElementsByClassName('morph-button').length);
                   console.log('observer2',document.getElementsByClassName('morph-button'));

                   var list = document.getElementsByClassName('morph-button');
                    console.log('list', list.length);

                   // var i;

                    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                        console.log('list iteration', list);
                        console.log('list index', i);

                        new UIMorphingButton( list[i], {
                            closeEl: '.icon-close',
                            onBeforeOpen: function () {

                                noScroll();

                            },
                            onAfterOpen: function () {

                                canScroll();

                            },
                            onBeforeClose: function () {

                                noScroll();

                            },
                            onAfterClose: function () {

                                canScroll();

                            }
                        });

                    }

                });

                observer.observe(divArray, { attributes: false, childList: true, subtree: true });

                // When you've got what you need, you should call this function to trigger a disconnect 
                function classesFound(){
                   observer.disconnect();
                };
```

Comment: solved only new browser, in IE not work